# Write to cell in excel using c# error

Tags: c#, excel

I am getting error **"Not enough storage is available to complete this operation"** during writing to cell in excel using c#.

I know that excel sheet not allows us to write more than 32,767 characters per cell.
I am writing 32,000 characters per cell. 
It allows me to write first 3 cell in 1st columns but for the 4th, it throws the above error. what is the reason of that? any idea?

**TOTAL LENGTH OF xml_txt_length is 2,65,000.**

**I have marked code by *************** in comments below where i am getting error.**
my code is below:

```
        if (xml_txt_length > 32000)  // checking length of text is more than 32,000. if yes than need to split it to write in cell
        {
            int counter = 0; // used to multiply to 32,000
            while (true)
            {
                if (counter == 0)
                {
                    cell_string = xmlText.Substring(0, 32000);
                    xml_string += cell_string;
                    // writing to cell for column1
                    oSheet3.Cells[counter + 1, 1] = cell_string;
                }

                else
                {
                    // if taken 32,000 characters exceeds the end length of string then go into this condition and take actual final position.  
                    if ((32000 * counter) + 32000 >= xml_txt_length) 
                    {
                        // below substring taking start position and up to end character of string instead of putting directly last 32,000th character position

                        cell_string = xmlText.Substring(32000 * counter, Convert.ToInt32(xml_txt_length - (32000 * counter)));

                        xml_string += cell_string;

                        //writing to cell for column 1
                        oSheet3.Cells[counter + 1, 1] = cell_string;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // taking the start and upto 32,000 characters from string
                        cell_string = xmlText.Substring(32000 * counter, 32000);
                        xml_string += cell_string;

                        // writing to cell for column 1
                        // ********************************************************
                        // **** HERE I AM GETTING ERROR FOR CELL 4 IN COLUMN 1 ****

                        oSheet3.Cells[counter + 1, 1] = cell_string;
                        cell_string = string.Empty;
                    }
                }

                if (counter >= Math.Floor(xml_txt_length / 32000))
                    break;
                counter++;
            }
        }
        else
            oSheet3.Cells[1, 1] = xmlText;
```

Comment: Recommendations from MS: http://technet.microsoft.com/library/Cc978736

Comment: Hi Juri, above suggestion not solving my problem. i have tested codes on 3 different pcs. i already have taken care of those 4 points mentioned in link.

Comment: Your `xml_string` keeps growing. Could it be the reason?

Comment: No. i am writing to excel cell from cell_string variable. Not from xml_string. Exception throws on "oSheet3.Cells[counter+1,1] = cell_string". i am not getting any idea why it throws error. this thing stop my project work. please help me out.

Comment: If you decrease the size of the chunk to 16k, will the error appear in row 8?

Comment: let me check and get back to you

Comment: i have decrease the chunk to 16,000 and now i am getting same error at counter value 6. what should i do? really this is headache :( . Any other idea?

Comment: there are 2,36,000 characters that i am spliting in 16,000 character chunk and writing every chunk to one by one cell. is there any character limits per sheets in excel ??